# Sources for tracking a ship in the 1840s

Tags: 19th-century, sources, ships, south-east-asia, south-africa

I am trying to determine the itinerary of a Danish ship that traveled in the "East Indies" 1841–43. I have its name, captain, departure from and return to Copenhagen.

Additionally, I have found about a dozen notices about its docking in various ports via the papers *Berlingske Tidende*, *Singapore Free Press*, and *Javasche Courant*. The ship is mentioned in the ports of Bali, Banyuwangi, Batavia (Jakarta), Manila, Padang, and Singapore.

Of note, *Javasche Courant* mentions that it was transporting Malwa opium in June 1842, ie. near the end of the First Opium War. Apparently, this opium was "a challenge to the monopoly of the British East India Company, which was supplying Bengal opium to China" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwa)).

From the known dates and locations, I have determined that the trip out took about 5 months, and the trip back about 7 months, so they would probably have needed supplies along the way.

I assume they travelled by the southern route, ie. via the Cape of Good Hope, and so I've gone through *De Zuid-Afrikaan*'s "Shipping Intelligence" columns for the relevant months, but I've had no luck there. They mostly mention British, Dutch, and French ships, but they do also mention Danish, German, Norwegian, and Swedish ships, so I'm unsure what the selection criteria was.

Are there other newspapers from Cape Town or even from other ports along the route that would be worth checking out? Are they or any similar sources online?

Comment: Do the paper De Zuid-Afrikaan mentions any finnish especially ships from Åland ?

Comment: @StefanSkoglund I don't recall seeing any, but I only looked at about a year's worth of shipping columns. They're on the last page of each issue and can be found here: https://digital.lib.sun.ac.za/handle/10019.2/1060 (unfortunately no text search)

Comment: It might be worth checking the Danish national archives, it may contain the ships logs for Danish ships of that era.

Comment: Also, Cape Town is a logical port to visit for such journeys, but it might be possible the ship didn't visit Cape Town,  but went to Port Elizabeth (now Qeberha), Durban, Maputo, Madagascar or Mauritius instead.

Comment: @Fred There are indeed good records for royal ships in the Nat'l Archives. Unfortunately, it was a private merchant vessel, so there is nothing in the archives. Thanks for the other port suggestions, I will look into possible newspapers